# Ubuntu User statistics sources and tools for stats

Tags: users, statistical

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many Ubuntu users are there worldwide ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80379/how-many-ubuntu-users-are-there-worldwide)

I am looking for Ubuntu information about an estimate of how many Ubuntu users exist. This includes all versions of Ubuntu like Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu and the rest of the supported one.

What pages or place where I can see information about existing users. Additionally what tools can be used by users to be involved in this statistics.